# Doubt in a method to determine the spectral terms for equivalent electrons

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

E. R. Tuttle in 1967 proposed a suitable method to determine the spectral terms for equivalent electrons in an atom in LS coupling condition. You may download the paper [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u_ihEgk6lSDfLVHLScg233B0XmzIX0sl/view?usp=drivesdk), or
[E. R. Tuttle; Terms Obtained from Configurations of Equivalent Electrons. Am. J. Phys. 1 January 1967; 35 (1): 26–29.](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1973853)

I am having the difficulty to understand it properly. You can read the method described in pictures below or just download the article from the above link.
[image]
[image]

So in the above mentioned method I don’t understand step (b) properly in II. METHOD section. As a consequence, I don’t understand why $L = 0$ or $S $ state is not considered after the term ${}^{4}P$ in the example in table I for $ nd^3 $ case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why $L = 0$ or $S $ state is not considered after the term ${}^{4}P$ in the example in table I for $ nd^3 $ case ?

The answer is the two $M_L=0$ entries after
$M_L=1$ entries belong to the last two spectral terms. We could have a $ L = 0 $ state if we had three $M_L =0$ entries instead of two.

Same for other terms. Check the picture below. [image]